# Numbered paragraphs with reportlab

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm trying to use **reportlab**, but I'm finding the user guide not clear enough.. *(maybe it's just me)*

I have the following code

```
    for item in content:
      text = item.name
      p = Paragraph(text,style,'*')
```

and it renders exactly as expected.

But what if I want **numbering** instead of **bullets**?

The user guide is really vague about this situation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [User Guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) has a part on this. If I understand correctly, you have to use a `<seq/>` tag instead of a bullet point for trivial numbering (each occurance counts one up). For more complex numbering see pages 73/74.

Example, as far as I understand, you put things like `<b> </b>` for bold textand `<seq/>` inline:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph

formatted_text = 
    "Some example text. <seq/>First. <seq/>Second. <seq/>Third"
formatted_para = Paragraph(your_formatted_text, your_paragraph_style_instance)
```

You will have to experiment a bit with line breaks. This one won't have any.

Comment: Yes, I've already read that. But still it's not clear to me how to do it. Can someone please give me a code example based on the code I've written in the question?

Comment: Thank you. This trick worked as expected. I think I feel a little bit disappointed with reportlab, because I was thinking about a different kind of solution...  Maybe something like `p = Paragraph(text,style,'<seq />')`... Anyway, thank you for helping me.

Comment: well it still beats having to generate TeX code, when super accurate layout and type setting isn't the main concern. Especially for tables and form-like stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but based on your example code you could do something like this:

```
paragraph_number = 1
for item in content:
    text = item.name
    p = Paragraph(text,style,str(paragraph_number))
    paragraph_number += 1
```

You can just replace the bullet character with whatever you like.